# How to turn off keyboard and lid lights for asus rog ubuntu 20.04 in SLEEP mode?

Tags: suspend, asus, hibernate, backlight, keyboard-backlight

I have a ROG Strix G731G and I already downloaded and use the rogauracore from this repository https://github.com/wroberts/rogauracore.git.

I use the `sudo rogauracore black` mode and the lights are off and everything is ok.

It works fine when the laptop is on, but as soon as I enter suspension (sleep mode) the lights turn red and start moving (bleeding effect).

It's very annoying because I need the darkness to sleep and I don't want to completely shut down the computer.

Does somebody know how to make rogauracore work also in sleep mode? Or does anyone know a trick to keep the keyboards and lid lights off during sleep mode?

Thanks

Edit: I need to control the lights (turn them off) in suspend mode. I have Ubuntu 20.04. I tried OpenRGB but it doesn't work on my computer (when running I get an error and already tried these solutions (["One or more I2C/SMBus interfaces failed to initialize."](https://www.reddit.com/r/OpenRGB/comments/thohk7/error_initializing_i2csmbus_interfaces/)) but it doesn't work). The only thing that works is rogauracore but this doesn't work in sleep mode.

Comment: Nothing OS related runs or can run when sleeping. If there's a away to avoid that behavior you will or won't find it in the firmware (UEFI).

Comment: I often wonder; starting a computer from scratch takes less than a minute, why then use "sleep mode" with all the problems it seems to have?  (Also a G731 here, no trouble whatsoever, starting anew each evening). Tip "OpenRGB".

Comment: @Hannu because I don't want to open all the windows again (not only chrome).

Comment: Openrgb doesn't work on my computer

Comment: NOTE: Many programs can be made start in sequence, e.g. at login, it may take a minute or so, but no need to manually click on each one.

Comment: `sudo rogauracore brightness 0` ?

Comment: @Hannu rogauracore works fine when the laptop in on, but not on sleep mode

Answer (score 1):

Boot into windows by selecting "windows boot manager" while booting up. Once signed in, press the rog button, which will bring you to what they call the "armoury crate". On the left, you'll see an icon that is a keyboard and a mouse, this icon is called "device" but it may be that if only shows "system", since that seems to be the only sub option (at least in my device).
Select "lighting" at the top,  and then "settings" to the right. The only options there for me are the toggles for sleep and awake. Toggle "sleep" off. Then just restart into Ubuntu.

Comment: I don't have Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "OpenRGB" - https://openrgb.org/

Note: I don't use "sleep mode" so haven't verified it to be a remedy for related problems.

---

This typed at the `$` prompt of a Shell/Terminal will display BIOS version and all that
*(hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd> at the end):*

```
for s in $(dmidecode --string 2>&1 | tail -n +4) ; \
do echo -en "$s: \t";sudo dmidecode --string $s ; done
```

Comment: OpenRGB doesn't work on my computer.

Comment: Well, sorry to hear that. I believe there is no "standard" on how these extra (meant to be) "cream on the top" functions are communicating with the outside world. It works well enough on my Asus G731GU w BIOS G731GU.310, to the extent that I was able to disable "the blinking".

Comment: I tried suspending my Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS;  A slowly flashing power button.

Comment: do you disable the backlights even in sleep mode?

Comment: This is the BIOS info

American Megatrends Inc.

bios-version:  G731GV.307

bios-release-date:  09/24/2019

system-manufacturer:  ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.

system-product-name:  ROG Strix G731GV_G731GV

system-version:  1.0       

system-serial-number:  K6NRCV015870234

system-uuid:  75b2f77c-e019-bb4b-859c-0bd37c1589b7

system-family:  ROG Strix

baseboard-manufacturer:  ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.

baseboard-product-name:  G731GV

baseboard-version:  1.0

Comment: baseboard-asset-tag:  ATN12345678901234567

chassis-manufacturer:  ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
chassis-type:  Notebook
chassis-version:  1.0       
chassis-serial-number:  K6NRCV015870234
chassis-asset-tag:  No Asset Tag
processor-family:  Core i7
processor-manufacturer:  Intel(R) Corporation
processor-version:  Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz
processor-frequency:  2475 MHz

Sorry, I don't know how to format it better

Comment: openrgb allowed me to disable the lights aflter installing i2c extras and using sudo (still it complained about something)

Comment: I have ROG Strix G513RW